# use a for each in a multiple type arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist, foreach, types

I have an Array List containing multiple Entity Objects and these Entity are of different type (because Entity is an abstract class). In this Array List that I'll call `myEntities` I have something like `[4x Zombies, 5x Plants, 6x Projectiles]` (shuffled). All these types extend `Entity` but I only want with a `for-each` loop to delete the Zombies. How can I do this?

PS: I can't use `instanceof`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you please share a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so we can reproduce your issue?

Comment: "PS: I can't use instanceof" since you can't use tool ideal for this job this may be yet another case of [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377). Consider using [edit] option and adding more context which explains why `instanceof` can't be used.

Comment: BTW foreach (enhanced for loop) can't/shouldn't modify content of collection it iterates over (if you do you risk getting ConcurentModificationException to be thrown). If you are using Java 8 or later you can use `yourCollection.removeIf(Predicate)`.

Comment: Why can't you use `instanceof`?

Comment: minor editorial fixes to improve readability.

Comment: It's a school project and my teacher don't want us to us instanceof because it could become to easy... -.-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a structure like this:

```
static class foo{

  }

  static class bar{

  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<Object> a = new ArrayList<>();
    a.add(new foo());
    a.add(new bar());

    for (Object o: a) {
      if(o.getClass() == foo.class){
        a.remove(o);
      }
    }
  }
```

Hope that solves your Problem.